# How to change the webview url for android when the servlet is triggered

Tags: java, android, servlets, callback

My title might be confusing.

what I want to do is..

I have an android activity has webview.(Initially it is black), and I will call one servlet.
This servlet sends one of the social media's request-token and request-secret and it returns authorized URL for login. So, I want to change the URL from servlet and display on webview.

If anyone has any idea or questions, please response me. Thank you.

Comment: _I want to change the URL from servlet_ Rephrase that. You receive a URL. You don't want to use it?

Comment: Before I call the servlet, the url is blank. When the servlet is triggered, I want the url to change to authorized url which is given from the social media's server.